# How to send an iPhone app to someone?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

I would need to send my iPhone game to a person. I am currently waiting for it to be approved on the App Store. Is there a way of sending the game over email or something like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share my iPhone app for testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754006/share-my-iphone-app-for-testing)

Comment: I don't know what you're using but you want to publish it "ad-hoc" and give the ipa file to whoever.  They copy it into itunes and install.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send the app to someone else, they can only get the app via the app store. If they have Xcode and an Apple Developer account though you could send them the source code and they could compile and deploy on their own devices. This is the only way.

Comment: You can't publish "ad-hoc" or specify their device id and just send apk?

Comment: ...woops, not apk, ipa

Answer (score 0):

You can use diawi or testflight to provide apps for beta testers.

[how does it work - testflight](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/821656-what-is-testflight-)

I used diawi and it worked fine for me.